# Getting result of Confirm dialog on Cancel Button in jQuery event hander

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener, confirm

On one side I have a form with submit/cancel buttons and the cancel has an **onclick** event (to do some cleanup) that is wrapped in a standard confirm dialog. All standard stuff.

But then I have a second script (and it MUST be a second script) that may only *sometimes* be loaded, that needs to add more tasks if the form is cancelled. So - I can listen for the onclick...

```
$( "#cancelBtn" ).on( "click", function(a) {
    // do more stuff...
});
```

but I only want to 'do more stuff' if the confirm around the onclick is OK. I am probably missing something stupidly simple but I have been at this all day and am about to give up! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Update: I can not change the form onclick code - it has to stay separate and as it now is.... so the confirm has to stay where it is.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
$( "#cancelBtn" ).on( "click", function(a) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?')) { // Standard confirmation message.
        // Pressed OK.
        // do more stuff...
    } else {
        // Pressed Cancel.
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Old answer but still helping. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since you can't change the script performing form duty, a solution would be to overwrite the `confirm()`-function:

```
var _confirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function() {
    //catch result
    var confirmed = _confirm.apply(window,arguments);
    if (confirmed) {
        //confirm ok, do some tasks
    } else {
        //confirm cancelled, do some cleanup
    }
    //pass result on to the caller
    return confirmed;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sofcuoab/

---

put the tasks in the second script in

```
function doMoreStuff(){
    //more tasks
}
```

and call it in your confirm-clause like this

```
if (typeof doMoreStuff === "function") {
    doMoreStuff();
}
```

or like this

```
try {
    doMoreStuff();
}
catch(err) {
    //no second script loaded
}
```

Comment: Both nice tries and I thank you for them. I should have made it clear in the question that I can not change the script performing form duty. The logic has to be in the second script.

Comment: I updated my answer with an overwritten `confirm()`-function. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Chris. i am starting to think my best approach is to revisit the structure completely. I am surprised that there is no way of telling if an 'onclick' script has run or been stopped  by the confirmation. Really was thinking there must be something basic I was overlooking!